# cheese cake cooking times

Tags: baking, cooking-time, cheesecake

I usually bake a 10" New York style cheese cake.  cheese cakes. On my 10", I bake it for 45 minutes at 350 degrees, shut off the oven but leave the cake in for another hour before removing. I now want to use the same recipe and make a few 4.5" cheese cakes. How do I convert the baking time for these smaller ones?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm guessing "try and adjust" is going to be your best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recipe for four 4.5" cheesecakes that should be exactly what you need. I haven't used the recipe myself but it certainly seems reasonable:

http://www.food.com/recipe/four-4-5-inch-cheesecakes-with-nine-stir-in-variations-506199

The crust is cooked for 7 minutes at 300F and the while cheesecake is cooked for 40-45 minutes at 300F.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest testing it after half the time for the full size. A good way to check is to inset a thin skewer into the cake, if it comes out gooey, it is not finished, so try again after ~ 10 minutes.

Comment: this is a good general answer for cakes, but we are talking about a cheesecake here, its filling stays gooey even after it is done

Comment: I've had good success with this method for cheesecakes; make them a lot.